# Misuse of 'property' reserved word

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, decorator

So I have some god forsaken legacy code that uses the reserved word `property`, um wrong. In a base class that gets inherited they have basically implemented.

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, property):
        self._property = property

    @property
    def property(self):
        return self._property


test = TestClass('test property')
print(test.property)
```

Which runs without error. If you add another method below that you get,

```
class TestClass2(object):

    def __init__(self, property):
        self._property = property

    @property
    def property(self):
        return self._property

    @property
    def other_property(self):
        return 'test other property'


test = TestClass2('test property')
print(test.property)
print(test.other_property)
```

Which throws:

```
---> 10     @property
     11     def other_property(self):
     12         print('test other property')

TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

Because you know you have overwritten `property` in the local namespace.

```
class TestClass3(object):

    def __init__(self, property):
        self._property = property

    @property
    def other_property(self):
        return 'test other property'

    @property
    def property(self):
        return self._property


test = TestClass3('test property')
print(test.property)
print(test.other_property)
```

You can work around this if you always define your `property` overwrite at the bottom of your class. If the `property` method is only defined on the base class you inherit from things also work out, because namespaces.

```
class TestClass4(TestClass):

    def __init__(self, property):
        super(TestClass4, self).__init__(property)

    @property
    def other_property(self):
        return 'test other property'


test = TestClass4('test property')
print(test.property)
print(test.other_property)
```

My righteous indignation says that we MUST update this variable name in the huge amount of legacy code, because GAAAAH, but other than having to remember to add new methods above the definition of `property` definition in the rarely modified base class, this doesn't actually break anything right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**dont shadow builtins...** with almost no refactoring at all you can avoid shadowing the builtin entirely

use `__getattr__` instead of `@property` to return your `_property` member ...

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._property = 12

    def __getattr__(self,item):
        if item == "property": 
           #do your original getter code for `property` here ... 
           # now you have not overwritten the property keyword at all
           return getattr(self,"_property") # just return the variable
class TestClass2(TestClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self._property = 67

print TestClass2().property

class MySubClass(TestClass):
    @property
    def a_property(self):
        return 5

print MySubClass().property
print MySubClass().a_property
```

really, as an aside, theres not any good reason imho to use `@property` in python.  all it does is end up confusing other programmers later and obscuring the fact that you are actually calling a function. I used to do it regularly ... I now avoid it unless I have a very very compelling reason not to

Comment: downvoter reason? im ok with a downvote but im curious as to why?

Comment: There's many reasons to use property.  It's fairly pythonic to expose your api via attributes instead of accessors and mutators, but that would mean you couldn't calculate values lazily, or have side effects when people set values.  `property` allows you to have the best of both worlds.

Comment: there are no private variables in python ... and all i said was an opinion I certainly am not stopping him from using property ... my opinion is pretty irrellevant to my answer which imho is the correct answer to the question posed ...

Comment: @BrendanAbel: I  agree that `@property` is handy, but I don't see the point of using it to implement access of a static attribute. If later changes need that attribute to be dynamic or require side-effects on access (yuck), then you create the property method. Why bloat the code and slow it down prematurely?

Comment: @PM2Ring Without property.setters, property also makes an attribute read-only (to some extent).

Comment: @BrendanAbel: Fair point. OTOH, "we're all consenting adults here".

Comment: I think this is the best fix for removing the shadow of the built in.... I mean without refactoring, which is the right fix.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you *always* add new methods above the definition of the `property` method nothing will break. So put a nice big comment to that effect in the code. Hopefully, anyone wanting to override `property` in a derived class will look at the base class first and see your comment...

BTW, the `property` arg to the `__init__` method also shadows `property`, but I guess that's not an issue.

Ideally, someone should clean this mess up, but I understand that it may not be cost-effective to do that.

Also, I'm somewhat baffled why the original coder made `property` an @property in the first place. That construct should only be used when the value of the attribute has to be calculated dynamically, not for simply returning a static attribute. Perhaps they were new to Python and they were told that's the way to do getters in Python...

Comment: meh the local shadowing isnt a big deal unless he's planning on refactoring ... but +1 for refactor to not shadow builtins :P

Comment: man that comment made no sense ... I musta been tired, I meant "... unless he plans on creating new classes inside that local scope"

Comment: Thanks for answering my actual question. I'm accepting the other response, because it has a nice suggestion for removing the shadow.

Comment: @TristanMatthews: Not a problem. Joran deserves the tick; FWIW, I upvoted his answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could always remap `property` to another name.  So long as you choose a name that doesn't match your other class attributes, and it won't be exposed in the external interface for the class, so it doesn't really matter what you name it.

```
tproperty = property

class Test(...)

    @tproperty
    def property(self):
        ....
```

Comment: so if someone had named a variable `list` you would recommend assigning the original `list` to `tlist` and using `tlist(x)` everywhere instead of `list(x)` ?

Comment: No, just use `[]` instead of `list()` :)  But seriously, you can't *always* advocate for breaking an API, even if the naming decisions were very bad.  If the OP was fine with breaking the API, he wouldn't have asked the question, he would have just changed the name.  Remapping a builtin isn't unheard of, and it's certainly preferable than having a giant comment saying "this function has to be last in the class definition".